# Value of companies with circular ownership

Tags: microeconomics, mathematical-economics, finance, stock-market, financial-economics

> Given two companies, total assets of $100 million each.
>
> - Company 'A' owns \$50M of company 'B'.
> - Company 'B' owns \$50M of company 'A'.

If you look at the value of both companies do you get \$200M or \$100M in value?

Is there any effect of this in the stock market where there is lots of circular ownership?

Comment: Does the \$100 million of assets include the stock in the other company?